# java interface and return types

Tags: java, interface

I have been trying for a while, but now I'm wondering if I can. Is it possible for a method in an interface to return a variable or an array without needing two interfaces or methods(if possible)?

Comment: What? Why don't you try it?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Every method has to specify a return type and stick with it. There are no "union types" like "returns a String or an int[]".

If you really have a method that can return two different things, you can

- make a wrapper type (`StringOrIntArray`) that can hold both

or

- have the method return `Object` which can be pretty much anything, including arrays, and use `instanceof` at the caller to see what you got.

Both options are not particularly attractive. Maybe take a step back and rethink the bigger picture.

Comment: By reading this it becomes clearer (I think) what the OP was asking. +1

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with

```
interface Foo{
    int foo1();
    //or....
    int[] foo2();
}
```

?

Comment: because he does not want two methods

Comment: @user2310289 Thats why I put the `\\or....`. He doesnt need to put both of those functions in the interface, just the one he needs

Comment: so if he uses `int foo1();` - how does he return an array?

Comment: @user2310289 He doesnt. He said variable OR an array, not both.

Comment: so are you saying that the answer by @Thilo is meaningless.  If I say to you, please provide a service so that your customers can order coffee or tea, then if you provide a service that only serves tea, is this correct?

Comment: @user2310289 Your analogy is bad because in real life people can order two things at once. In programming a function returns 1 thing only. The better analogy would be 'provide a service so that customers can order 1 thing: coffee or tea`, in which case I would say yes, I am correct because I have one function for coffee and one for tea. Moreover the OP only wants one of them, otherwise he would have used the word *and*. You can not read into his intentions with your own.

Comment: Sorry, but I did mean both

Comment: @EmilioB. Then you should use the word and (it does make a difference as you can see!), and Thilo's answer is correct.

Comment: @Dgrin91 maybe you can now delete your answer